# How to avoid deadlock in processes executing in parallel through addition of another process in CSP

Tags: concurrency, deadlock, probe, fdr

PC1 and PC2 run in parallel with the same alphabet. They deadlock. I want to find a process (alphabet as yet undefined) which I can run in parallel with PC1 and PC2 which will solve the deadlock issue. Any ideas?

Regards.

This is my code file so far.

```
channel printA, printB, printC, printD

PC1 = printA -> printB -> printC -> printD

aPC1 = {printA, printB, printC, printD}

PC2 = printA -> printB -> printD -> printC

aPC2 = {printA, printB, printC, printD}

DEADLOCKAVOIDANCE = ?

aDEADLOCKAVOIDANCE = {?}

P = (PC1 [aPC1||aPC2] PC2) [union(PC1,PC2)||aDEADLOCKAVOIDANCE] DEADLOCKAVOIDANCE
```